# Difference in tests for linear models and significance levels adjustment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, linear-model

**Context**
Imagine we measure two outcomes $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{Z}$ that are real vectors. We also have the following covariates $G,T, X_1,\cdots,X_k$ for a given integer $k>1$. $G$ represents a group and can take either the value $0$ or $1$ and $T$ is the time and it is a categorical variable with several possible levels and $X_1,\cdots,X_k$ are any other possible variables that are at disposal.

*I added a lot of mathematical details that may appear not really useful. Personally, it helps me to understand what is going on. I have some trouble sometimes when we speak only about models really generally, I hope it is ok for everyone.*

The goal is to answer to these four questions:

1. Is $\mathbf{Y}$ changing over time?
2. Is $\mathbf{Y}$ different for $G=0$ or $G=1$?
3. Is $\mathbf{Z}$ changing over time?
4. Is $\mathbf{Z}$ different for $G=0$ or $G=1$?

Imagine that we want to test these hypotheses with linear models and, that we construct them using backward selection. The full models are the following:

- $Y = \theta_{y,1} G + \theta_{y,2} T + \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_{y,i} X_i$,
- $Z = \theta_{z,1} G + \theta_{z,2} T + \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_{z,i} X_i$,

where $\theta_{y,1},\theta_{z,1},\theta_{y,2},\theta_{z,2},\beta_{y,1},\cdots,\beta_{y,k},\beta_{z,1},\cdots,\beta_{z,k}$ are the parameters of the model.

Let's say, that after the backward selection process, we end up with these models for $m,l \leq k$:

- $Y = \theta_{y,1} G + \theta_{y,2} T + \sum_{i=1}^m \beta_{y,i} X_i$,
- $Z = \theta_{z,1} G + \theta_{z,2} T + \sum_{i=1}^l \beta_{z,i} X_i$.

**Methods 1**
One way to test the hypothesis 1. and 2. together, is to use the F-test to show that the parameters' $$\theta_{y,1}$ and $\theta_{y,2}$ are non-zero. In my lecture note, the procedure would be as follows:

Let us define $\theta_y = (\theta_{y,1},\theta_{y,2},\beta_{y,1},\cdots,\beta_{y,m} )^t$, $\hat{\theta_y}$ the LSE of $\theta_y$, $p = m + 2$  and $\psi$ the $2\times p$ following matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$,
$D$ the design matrix, $\Gamma = (\psi^t (D^tD)^{-1}\psi)^{-1}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ the estimate of the standard deviation squared.

The hypothesis 1. can be reformulate as $\theta_{y,2} \neq 0$ and the hypothesis 2. as $\theta_{y,1}\neq 0$. The test statistic is
$$
F = \frac{(\psi^t \hat{\theta_y})^t\Gamma(\psi^t \hat{\theta_y})}{2\hat{\sigma}^2}
$$.

The statistic F follows the F distribution with $2$ and $n-p$ degrees of freedom, where $n$ is the number of observations. If the p-value is lower or equal to the significance level, then we reject both hypotheses. So, in this case as much as I understand, we do not need to adjust for the confidence level.

**Methods 2**
Now imagine that I conduct two different T-tests with $\psi_1 = (1,0,\cdots,0)^t$ and $\psi_2 = (0,1,0,\cdots,0)^t$, two $p \times 1$ vectors. The two statistics for the corresponding hypotheses are:

-$T_1 = \frac{\psi^t \hat{\theta}}{\hat{\sigma_{\psi_1}}} $,
-$T_2 = \frac{\psi^t \hat{\theta}}{\hat{\sigma_{\psi_2}}}$,

with $\hat{\sigma_{\psi_i}}^2= \hat{\sigma_i}^2\psi_i^t(D^tD)^{-1}\psi$. $T_i$ follows a t-distribution with $n-p$ degrees of freedom.

**Questions**
In the following, the significance level will be denoted $\alpha$.

1. Imagine that we use method 1 for $Y$ and we reject the null hypothesis, is it sufficient to say that $Y$ is changing over time and that that it is different for $G=0,1$ ? Do we need to adjust for the significance level? I understand that method 1 is testing if hypotheses 1 AND hypothesis 2 is false, but I am still a bit confused with it.
2. Imagine that we use method 2 for $Y$ to test the two hypotheses, do we need to adjust for the coefficient level?
3. Do we need to adjust the confidence level when we test the hypotheses for $Y$ and $Z$ since the the models rely on he same variables/observations? Would be the significance level (with Bonferroni) equal to $\alpha/4$. If yes, can you please explain?

Comment: Backwards selection is not a good idea. This has been discussed here many times.  See the "stepwise" tag which also covers backward  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stepwise-regression